# Success callback for POST requests sent with form element

Tags: jquery, html, forms, post, callback

I'm just wondering if there is a way to be notified (on the client side) when you submit a POST request with the HTML form element.

Is there a method of implementing logic based on the data sent back to the browser (similar to jQuery's `success` callback function) after a POST request has been sent to the server.

With jQuery `$.ajax()` I can implement logic in the callback function based on what the server sends to me (like put data in some element if the data is x). Can I possibly do something similar with the native form element --> `<form method="POST">` ?

Comment: nope, regular html/php will cause the page to reload

Comment: Ahh Ok I see so the only work around I guess would be to use ajax for the request

Comment: yes use ajax, ajax is good!

Comment: But but .. the form element has 'Enter' click handler built in :(